# Android setError does not follow the slide down animation

Tags: android

I have the following page in my android app (I cannot take screenshot of the page so i simply draw it): I have edittexts and i use edittext's showError property.

[image]

Then, at some point of the program, the whole page animates and slides down. The problem is, when edittexts slide down, the error message does not slide, it holds its position and becomes like this:

[image]

Here is my layout file for the edittexts:

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/loginFieldsPanel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loginWarningPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_edit_fields_bg">
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/userNamePanel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/userNameWithBg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/login_eposta_image_bg"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/login_username_left_image"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <com.example.CustomEditText
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/editUserName"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userNameWithBg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    custom:customFontType="regular"
                    android:hint="@string/login_identity_hint"
                    android:background="@null"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/login_fields_line"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userNamePanel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/login_fileds_line"/>
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_fields_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/passwordWithBg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/login_password_image_bg"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/login_password_left_image"/>
                </RelativeLayou
                <com.example.CustomEditText
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passwordWithBg"
                    android:id="@+id/editPassword"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    custom:customFontType="regular"
                    android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how i perform the animation:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(basePanel, "translationY", start, finish).setDuration(duration).start();
```

where basePanel is the root layout of my layout file.

So, can anyone help me to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The simple way is for the outer layout to add this attribute:   `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`.
2. Here are two methods to let the view start slide up and slide down.

   ```
   public TranslateAnimation getShow()
   {
       TranslateAnimation mShowAction = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
       mShowAction.setDuration(500);
       return mShowAction;
   }

   public TranslateAnimation getHide()
   {
       TranslateAnimation mHiddenAction = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,   
               0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,   
               Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,   
               -1.0f);  
       mHiddenAction.setDuration(500); 
       return mHiddenAction;
   }
   ```

   How to use it:

   ```
   view.startAnimation(getShow());
   ```